# What is faster on million rows, filter rows by 1 varchar column or 2-3 integer columns

Tags: mysql

On my database i have the following columns:
[int]userid, [int]value1id, [int]value2id, [int]value

My question is when using select/update/insert on million of rows what would be better for performance/overhead.

Using the database like above or something like this:
[varchar]useridValue1idValue2id , [int]value

Example query option 1  [Where columns are integer]:

```
Select value
FROM database1
WHERE userid = :userid AND value1id = :value1id AND value2id = :value2id
```

Example query option 2 [where column is varchar]:

```
Select value
FROM database1
WHERE useridValue1idValue2id = :useridValue1idValue2id
```

Comment: well what indexes do you have?

Comment: [Race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @OldProgrammer   each of this column will have to use a index, so 1 index over 3 columns for option1 and 1 index for option 2.

Comment: I predict that there won't be enough difference i speed to matter.  That is, the hassle of combining the columns won't be worth the effort.